# Select listbox item using the keyboard in swing

Tags: java, swing

Could anyone please tell me what i should do programmatically to be able to select an item in a listbox using the keyboard when there are multiple items starting with the same character/s. For eg,

```
•One
 •Two
 •Three
 •Once
 •Orange
```

If i want to get the focus on "Once" by typing o,n,c what should i do? Instead of jumping from one item to the other as opposed to the default behaviour.

Comment: you are looking for "autocomplete" functionality (if I understand the question correctly, at last :-) - there are several open source packages available, f.i. [SwingX autocomplete](http://swingx.java.net)

Answer (score 1):

Add a KeyPress event handler to the ListBox and track the keys that are presses. Then compare the complete value that already has been typed to the values from the items in the ListBox. If there's a match, select the item.

Comment: I would favor key bindings over key listeners, it tends to produce cleaner code are generally less troublesome...IMHO